# How to get access token for a Google Workspace account valid for all users

Tags: google-api, gmail, google-oauth, google-directory-api

I have one Google workspace account for which I want to get access token which I can use to call APIs for all users of that workspace account.

```
private static GoogleCredential getCredentials(HttpTransport httpTransport, String serviceAccountUser) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

        URL keyFileUrl = GSuiteProcessor.class.getResource(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH);

        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(JACKSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_ID)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(List.of(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER, GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM))
                .setServiceAccountUser(serviceAccountUser)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new java.io.File(keyFileUrl.getPath()))
                .build();

        return credential;
    }
```

So, this is the code snippet I am using to get access token (GoogleCredential) and using it I am doing some GMail API calls to access user's emails. Something like below

```
private static Gmail getGmailService(final String user) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Credential credential = getCredentials(httpTransport, user);

        Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(httpTransport, JACKSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();

        return service;
}


private static void getMailDetails() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        String user = SERVICE_ACCOUNT_USER_EMAIL;
        Gmail service = getGmailService(user);

        ListLabelsResponse listResponse = service.users().labels().list(user).execute();
        List<Label> labels = listResponse.getLabels();
        System.out.println("Labels : " + labels.size());
        //labels.stream().forEach(l -> System.out.println(l.getName()));

        List<Thread> threads = service.users().threads().list(user).execute().getThreads();
        System.out.println("Messages : " + threads.size());
}
```

So here for each workspace user I need to get token each time and then proceed further.

So, is there any way by that I can have access token for all the users so that I can use that token for calling GMail APIs. I mean token at workspace account level and not user level.

Note : I did all prerequisite steps like creating service account, enabling domain wide delegation for service account in workspace account.